# Regular expression in .net to exclude a particular word and multiple whitespaces and line breaks

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I need a regex for finding a substring like

```
from xyzTableName     with   (  index =...
```

and

```
from xyzTableName     (  index =...
```

If `with` keyword is not there then it should return a match and if `with` exists after `FROM` keyword and before `(` then there should be no match. All the other words between `from` and `(` must be ignored.

I have tried with below expression :

```
    @"\bfrom.*[\s\t\n]+(?<!with)[\s\t\n]([\s\t\n]+index"
```

And some variants of same. I was able to work it out when there are only normal/single whitespaces. But when I tried with multiple white-spaces and line-breaks, It failed.

Comment: I tried with @"\bfrom.*[\s\t\n]+(?<!with)[\s\t\n]\([\s\t\n]+index" but no luck....I am just missing something...I know I am almost there but not able to figure out..It works well when there is normal query but when I am trying with multiple white-spaces and line-breaks it fails. I just wanted to keep question simple that's why did not posted everything...I am not seeking any help in home work  .:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern: `\bfrom\b(?!.+\bwith\b)[^(]+\(\s*index`

```
string input = @"from xyzTableName     
with   (  index =...";
string pattern = @"\bfrom\b(?!.+\bwith\b)[^(]+\(\s*index";
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern,
                RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The above returns `false`. Change the input to remove the word "with" and it will return `true`. By using `RegexOptions.Singleline` the `.` metacharacter will match all characters, including newlines (`\n`).

Pattern breakdown:

- `\bfrom\b`: exactly matches the word "from" and uses word-boundary metacharacters
- `(?!.+\bwith\b)`: negative look-ahead to check for "with" and the match will fail if it does
- `[^(]+`: negative character class to match any character that is not an opening parenthesis, at least once.
- `\(\s*index`: match an opening parenthesis (note that it has to be escaped), any whitespace, then the word "index"

Comment: It worked, "from xyzTableName with ( index =..." in this case expected is false only. That was the main ask only..